# How can I insert data at run time that has to be updated into Mysql Database

Tags: c++, mysql

Now, I'm using this code to insert the values into table.

**mysql_query(connect, "insert into users values (5, 'John', 'Mathew', True)");**

This line inserts the values into MySQL database.

Suppose if the table has to be updated by the values given by user from the console.
How I need to write the query in my c++ program.

Comment: im not a c++ guru, but i think what you need to do is save that data provided on run time, and pass that data to the query...how hard can that be, and you are saying that you need to update the data but your query is for the INSERT. check that too.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and provide a clear explanation of what your problem is, possibly with some code. As it's now, the question is totally unclear and you'll only get answers on random subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.. but what i get is like

You want to insert some values in table, if values are already present than you need to update it else insert. than you can use "insert.. update" statement available with mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: waiting for reply...please can anyone answer this question